# AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath vs Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I just need my app to know where to look for some unmanaged dlls. I am using `SetEnvironmentVariable` and it is working great. I know that there is also a property `AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath`. What is the practical difference between them?

Currently I am doing it as below:

```
var dllDirectory = @"C:\some\path";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + dllDirectory)
```

Edit:
I noticed that Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable does not actually change the PATH variable, it seams to affect only the app that have called it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrivateBinPath is where the CLR will look for assemblies.

Which is *not* where Windows will look for DLLs, it doesn't know anything about CLR configuration.  It uses the regular Windows search rules, which usually behaves like this:

1. same directory as where the EXE is stored
2. the directory specified in a Set/AddDllDirectory() call, if any
3. the Windows system directory (normally c:\windows\system32)
4. the Windows install directory (normally c:\windows)
5. the current default directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory)
6. the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

Several quirks to this, it has been tinkered with a lot.  Particularly bullet 5 is a security problem and can be abused to get a program to load a rogue DLL.  But close enough to what you can expect in the wild.

Setting the PATH environment variable in your code is okayish, it is not exactly reliable.  It being on the *bottom* of the list is of course an issue, you might get the wrong DLL loaded.  And the PATH environment variable itself is troublesome, it can easily be corrupted on a machine and may be already too long to allow you to append another directory to it.  Very hard to diagnose problems.

You should always, *always*, **always** favor bullet 1.  Simply copy the native DLLs into the same directory as your EXE.  Always works, always reliable, never a surprise, no special config needed.  Nobody cares that this directory is a bit full, not your customer, not the file system, not the operating system.

If you have to then always favor bullet 2, pinvoke [SetDllDirectory()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetDllDirectory.html).  It is not completely reliable, you'll have trouble if one of the DLLs you load is using it too.  But you quickly find that out.  Using AddDllDiretory() is better but it isn't supported on enough Windows versions yet to be relied upon.

Comment: Thank for the info, just to clarify, PrivateBinPath will not work for unmanaged dlls?

Comment: "Which is not where Windows will look for DLLs".  That means "will not work".

Comment: More info: "AddDllDirectory() is a very recent addition to the winapi. It is only guaranteed to be available in Windows 8, getting it on earlier Windows versions requires an update, KB2533623"

Answer (score 0):

`AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath` is set of folders under application base directory that are probed for private assemblies during appdomain setup.  Env var `PATH` will not be necessarily pointing to folders under application base directory. `PATH` will contain any arbitrary folder path.